# Having trouble creating a Like system for comments in a Laravel Project

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I'm creating a project using Laravel. Users are able to like comments. I want to display a "like" button so a user can like a comment and if the user has already liked the comment I want that button to be "unlike" so a user can unlike the liked comment

In my database I have a likes table:

```
| id | user_id | comment_id |
```

My Like Model looks like this:

```
class Like extends \Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'comment_id'];
    protected $table = 'likes';

    public function owner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Acme\Users\User', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Comment Model looks like this:

```
class Comment extends \Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'post_id', 'body'];
    protected $table = 'comments';

    public function owner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Acme\Users\User', 'user_id');
    }
    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Acme\Likes\Like');
    }
}
```

User model:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Acme\Comments\Comment');
    }
    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Acme\Likes\Like');
    }

}
```

Likes controller :

```
class LikesController extends \BaseController {

use CommanderTrait;

/**
 * Like a comment
 * @return Response
 */
public function commentLike()
{
// using a command bus. Basically making a post to the likes table assigning user_id and comment_id then redirect back
    extract(Input::only('user_id', 'comment_id'));
    $this->execute(new CommentLikeCommand($user_id, $comment_id));

    return Redirect::back();
}
public function unlike()
{
    $like = new Like;
    $user = Auth::user();
    $id = Input::only('comment_id');
    $like->where('user_id', $user->id)->where('comment_id', $id)->first()->delete();
    return Redirect::back();
}
}
```

In my view I'm able to get the comments via $comment, and I'm able to get likes via $comment->like have:

```
@foreach($post->comments as $comment)
<div class="user-comment">
    <p class="comment">
        {{ $comment->owner->first_name }}&nbsp;{{ $comment->owner->last_name }}&nbsp;{{ $comment->body }}
    </p>

    <div class="com-details">
<!-- how long ago the comment was posted -->
    <div class="com-time-container">
        &nbsp;{{ $comment->created_at->diffForHumans() }} ·
    </div>

<!-- HERE IS WHERE I WANT THE LIKE AND UNLIKE BUTTONS TO DISPLAY -->
    @if ($comment->likes->owner->id === $currentUser->id)
        {{ Form::open(['route' => 'like']) }}
            {{ Form::hidden('user_id', $currentUser->id) }}
            {{ Form::hidden('comment_id', $comment->id) }}
            <button type="submit" class="com-like">Like</button>
        {{ Form::close() }}
    @else
        {{ Form::open(['route' => 'unlike']) }}
            {{ Form::hidden('user_id', $currentUser->id) }}
            {{ Form::hidden('comment_id', $comment->id) }}
            <button type="submit" class="com-like">Unlike</button>
        {{ Form::close() }}
    @endif
<!-- how many users like this comment -->
    <span class="likes"> · {{ $comment->likes->count() }}</span>
    </div>
</div><!--user-comment end-->
@endforeach
```

Im trying to set up an if statement to see if the current user has liked the status but im not sure how this is done? If the user has not liked the comment yet I want the "like" button to display. If the user has liked the comment I want the "unlike" button to display. I thought I could say `@if($comment->likes->owner->id === $currentUser->id)` but I get Undefined property. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$comment->likes` is a Collection of `Like` objects. To access the `owner` property, you would need to iterate the collection.

However, another option is to use the available methods on the Collection to do what you need:

```
@if (in_array($currentUser->id, $comment->likes->lists('user_id')))
```

`$comment->likes->lists('user_id')` will return an array of all the `user_id` values in the Collection of Likes for the Comment. `in_array()` will check if the `$currentUser->id` is in that array.

Comment: This is very clean and simple.Thank you! Works great.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked much with Laravel, so my syntax and terminology might be a bit off, but it should be the right idea.

Basically, `$comment->likes` is a list of likes on that comment. You need to iterate through those likes and check if one of them is by the current user. If one of them is by the current user, then show the unlike button. Otherwise, show the like button.

Not sure what that'd look like in Blade, but here's some pseudo-code:

```
$currentUserLiked = false;

// go through all of the comment's likes
foreach ($comment->likes as $like)
{
    // check if this like is by the current user
    if ($like->owner->id == $currentUser->id)
    {
        $currentUserLiked = true;
        break;
    }
}

if ($currentUserLiked)
{
    showUnlikeButton();
}
else
{
    showLikeButton();
}
```